# Which approach out of two is better?

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Database schema:**

- table SHOP (with columns SHOP_ID, SHOP_TYPE, SHOP_NAME, SHOP_ADDRESS, SHOP_PHONE, SHOP_OWNER)
- table PURCHASE (with columns PURCHASE_ID, PURCHASE_SUM, SHOP_ID)

**The task is:**

To get information about all shops with given TYPE (information should include the sum of money that was received in specific shop).

I know 2 approaches to complete that task.

**FIRST approach:**

```
SELECT 
    SHOP_NAME, 
    SHOP_ADDRESS, 
    SHOP_PHONE, 
    SHOP_OWNER,
    SUM(PURCHASE_SUM) AS SHOP_SUM
FROM
    PURCHASE
JOIN
    SHOP ON SHOP.SHOP_ID = PURCHASE.SHOP_ID
WHERE 
    SHOP_TYPE = 5
GROUP BY
    PURCHASE.SHOP_ID, SHOP_NAME, SHOP_ADDRESS, SHOP_PHONE, SHOP_OWNER
```

**SECOND approach:**

```
SELECT  
    SHOP_NAME, 
    SHOP_ADDRESS, 
    SHOP_PHONE, 
    SHOP_OWNER,
    TABLE1.PURCHASE_SUM AS SHOP_SUM
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        PURCHASE.SHOP_ID, 
        SUM(PURCHASE_SUM) AS SHOP_SUM
    FROM
        PURCHASE
    JOIN
        SHOP ON SHOP.SHOP_ID = PURCHASE.SHOP_ID
    WHERE 
        SHOP_TYPE = 5
    GROUP BY
        PURCHASE.SHOP_ID
) AS TABLE1
JOIN
    SHOP ON SHOP.SHOP_ID = TABLE1.SHOP_ID
```

**Question:**

FIRST approach seems to be more efficient because it has 1 JOIN and SECOND approach - 2 JOINs.

SECOND approach seems to be more clear and flexible because it doesn't have unnecessary GROUP BY's.

So.. Which approach is better?

Comment: Check the execution plans

Comment: "Better" is a matter of perspective, what do you consider better? You mention efficiency (pertaining to performance?), readability and flexibility, but what do you consider important in this matter?

Comment: This is opinion based, but I think that the first approach is cleaner and better. If you are too lazy to write all the `GROUP BY` columns, you should also be too lazy to write that extra subquery.

Comment: Relation names and fields should be lowercase unless they're quoted.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes `SHOP_ID` has primary key then you can use `subquery`

```
select *,
       (select sum(PURCHASE_SUM) from PURCHASE where SHOP_ID = s.SHOP_ID) as SHOP_SUM 
from SHOP s
where SHOP_TYPE = 5;
```

However, i would also recommend to use `join` instead (which you have already done with `GROUP BY`) For the performance  this would required index on (`SHOP_ID`)

Comment: This is probably the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

If by better you mean more efficient, then the best solution to is [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). Check the execution plans, run tests etc.

But I would present two adaptaton of your approaches. For your second option you can remove the join from the inner query, and move the filter on `SHOP_TYPE` to the outer query:

```
SELECT  
    SHOP.SHOP_NAME, 
    SHOP.SHOP_ADDRESS, 
    SHOP.SHOP_PHONE, 
    SHOP.SHOP_OWNER,
    TABLE1.PURCHASE_SUM AS SHOP_SUM
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        PURCHASE.SHOP_ID, 
        SUM(PURCHASE.PURCHASE_SUM) AS SHOP_SUM
    FROM
        PURCHASE
    GROUP BY
        PURCHASE.SHOP_ID
) AS TABLE1
JOIN
    SHOP ON SHOP.SHOP_ID = TABLE1.SHOP_ID
WHERE 
    SHOP.SHOP_TYPE = 5
```

This reduces the group by columns without introducing an additional `JOIN`.

For your first option, more recent versions of Postgresql allow you to include non key columns from a table in the select without grouping by them, if you are already grouping by the primary key, so assuming that `SHOP_ID` is the primary key of `SHOP` you could use:

```
SELECT 
    SHOP.SHOP_NAME, 
    SHOP.SHOP_ADDRESS, 
    SHOP.SHOP_PHONE, 
    SHOP.SHOP_OWNER,
    SUM(PURCHASE.PURCHASE_SUM) AS SHOP_SUM
FROM
    PURCHASE
JOIN
    SHOP ON SHOP.SHOP_ID = PURCHASE.SHOP_ID
WHERE 
    SHOP.SHOP_TYPE = 5
GROUP BY
    SHOP.SHOP_ID;
```

My preference is for the first query, but again, your best bet is to race your horses.

Comment: In my experience the first approach (which I sometimes call "aggregate first, join later") usually gives better performance